# How to stop interval function

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm trying to stop with `return` syntax:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
         var url = "../view/anychange.php";
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          f(data.exists == 0){
        alert("0"); 
          } else {
        alert("1");
            return; 
          }
      });
    }, 5000);


   });
</script>
```

The function verifies every 5 seconds if there exists data in my table.

I need to stop the function when `data.exists == 1` ( the `alert("1")` ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var id;
      id = setInterval(function() {
         var idRefCopy = id; // You need this otherwise you'll get a reference exception
         var url = "../view/anychange.php";
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         if(data.exists == 0){
           alert("0"); 
         } else {
           alert("1");
           clearInterval(idRefCopy);
           return; 
         }
      });
    }, 5000);
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the interval inside a variable, and then clear it. Try this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
         var url = "../view/anychange.php";
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          if(data.exists == 0){
        alert("0"); 
          } else {
             clearInterval(interval);
          }
      });
    }, 5000);


   });
</script>
```

You have a typo in the code (i have fixed it here, its a "f" instead of "if" ;) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your interval, this will prevent your function from being fired again. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for interval reference.

This should be your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        var url = "../view/anychange.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            f(data.exists == 0) {
                alert("0"); 
            } else {
                alert("1");
                clearInterval(i);
            }
         });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about clearInterval?

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
}

function myStopFunction()
{
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: Downvoted for a) not using OPs code, 2) poor reference. Please use MDN or similar instead of the dubious w3fools

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest you do not hit your server unless you know your ajax was done

This example will check, but only after the server returned

```
var counter = 0;
function checkData() {
  var url = "../view/anychange.php";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    if (data.exists == 0) {
      $("#someContainer").html("Not yet on attempt #"+(counter++));
      setTimeout(checkData,5000);
    } else {
      $("#someContainer").html("found on attempt #"+(counter++));
    }
  });
}
$(function() {
  checkData();
});
```