# Can not stop the slider

Tags: javascript

Trying to make the most simple gallery. There is a button that turns the image `<button class = "play-pause">Play</ button>`. Clicking on it starts `setInterval`, but when pressed again need to have it stopped. How can this be done?

Here's a link to the sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/eL31q3eq/

My attempt:

```
document.querySelector('.play-pause').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(timer == null) clearInterval(timer);

    this.innerHTML = "Pause";

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        i = (i < images.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;
        img.src = images[i];
    }, 1000);

    timer = null;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop interval function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311662/how-to-stop-interval-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `clearInterval` takes the interval object as an argument, and clears it. You're setting `timer` to null, so you're asking it to clear `null` which means it won't do anything.

[WindowTimer.clearInterval - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

You need to use another variables to check the status of the play/pause button.

```
document.querySelector('.play-pause').addEventListener('click', function() {

if(playing === true) {
    this.innerHTML = 'Play';
    clearInterval(timer);
    playing = false;
    return;
}

this.innerHTML = "Pause";

timer = setInterval(function() {
    i = (i < images.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;
    img.src = images[i];
}, 1000);

playing = true;
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/eL31q3eq/2/

Comment: Something I did not quite understand your decision. http://jsfiddle.net/obh5tanL/1/

Comment: Hey Aleksandr, seems to work for me. Either way I updated my code to more closely reflect your style and added a working jsFiddle

Comment: In your post Old Fiddle, the one that was in my post.

Answer (score 2):

You are discarding the variable you need to stop the slideshow - solution here.

http://jsfiddle.net/obh5tanL/

Don't initialize your timer variable either.

```
document.querySelector('.play-pause').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        this.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
    else {
        this.innerHTML = "Pause";

        timer = setInterval(function() {
            i = (i < images.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;
            img.src = images[i];
        }, 1000);
    }

});
```